# KNN model gets 100% accuracy - should I trust the results?

Tags: r, machine-learning, knn

So I'm playing with the iris dataset and no matter what my value of k in the knn algorithm, I'm getting 100% accuracy. Have I gone wrong somewhere?
Here's my code using the in-built iris data frame.

```
library(caret)
set.seed(52)
irissplit <- createDataPartition(iris$Species, p=.8, list=FALSE, times=1)
train <- iris[irissplit, ]
test <- iris[-irissplit, ]

library(class)
model_knn <- list()
accuracy_knn <- numeric()
for (i in 1:10) {
 model_knn[[i]] <- knn(train[,-5], test[,-5], train$Species, k=i, prob=TRUE) 
 accuracy_knn[i] <- sum(model_knn[[i]]==test$Species)/length(test$Species)*100
}
accuracy_knn
```

Comment: Where does `createDataPartition` come from?

Comment: Its from the caret package. It partitions the dataset ready for splitting out into training and test sets.

Comment: No, never trust a 100% accuracy model. In fact, 100% accuracy always means that you've made a mistake in some step

Comment: By changing the `set.seed` it gives something different. The code seems correct.

Comment: Oh wow! I somehow managed to pick the optimum seed! Thanks for the comment though, glad to see I'm not losing my marbles.